# R-squared negative for a linear regression model - Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, linear-regression, activation-function

I built a neural network without an activation function, which is, therefore, a Linear regression Model:

```
def build_model():
  model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,)),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
  ])

  model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse',metrics=['mae','mse','mape',coeff_determination]) 

  return model
```

My coeff_dermination is determined as follows:

```
from keras import backend as K

def coeff_determination(y_true, y_pred):
    SS_res =  K.sum(K.square( y_true-y_pred )) 
    SS_tot = K.sum(K.square( y_true - K.mean(y_true) ) ) 
    return ( 1 - SS_res/(SS_tot + K.epsilon()) )
```

Mathematically, R-squared cannot be below 0 for a linear regression model because:
Explained variance + Error variance = Total variance.

But when I train the model above, R-squared can be at times negative.

Why? Thanks for your thoughts/lights

[image: Training model]

Answer (score 0):

R Squared can be negative if your model fits the data worse than simply returning the mean of the dataset you're predicting.

Check out [What Is R Squared And Negative R Squared](http://www.fairlynerdy.com/what-is-r-squared/) for more information.

One thing that might help - I would avoid using a recipe to calculate this! The examples I've found do not produce consistent results, especially with just one target variable. This gave me enormous headaches!

The correct thing to do is to use [`tensorflow_addons.metrics.RQsquare()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/metrics/RSquare). Tensorflow Add Ons is [on PyPi here](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow-addons/) and the documentation is a [part of Tensorflow here](https://www.tensorflow.org/addons). All you have to do is set `y_shape` to the shape of your output, often it is `(1,)` for a single output variable.